# Adding Custom Bar Plot Annotations in Seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am plotting values of programs with values in tens of millions. I would like to add a label/annotation to each bar of the plot that shows the value. However, I would like the values to be formatted to be cleaner. IE 51M or 5,100,000 vs 5100000

Thanks

Current Code

```
ax = sns.barplot(y='Value', x ='BA', data=ba, palette='Blues_d')
plt.ylabel("Program Value [$]", fontsize = 15)
plt.xlabel("Business Area", fontsize=15)
plt.title("Top Business Area by Values in Pipeline", fontsize=20)
ax = plt.gca()
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(tick.FuncFormatter(reformat_large_tick_values));
for p in ax.patches:
    ax.annotate(format(p.get_height(), '.0f'), 
                   (p.get_x() + p.get_width() / 2., p.get_height()), 
                   ha = 'center', va = 'center', 
                   xytext = (0, 7),
                   size=12,
                   textcoords = 'offset points')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Maybe replace `format(p.get_height(), '.0f')` by `f'{p.get_height():,.0f}'`? (This introduces a thousand separator)

Comment: Or `f'{p.get_height()*1e-6:.2f}M'`?

Comment: Thanks, I placed your code inside format and it worked!